# How to understand usages and definition of different cache manager of spring annotation

Tags: java, caching, spring-boot

We are using spring boot frame work and choose SimpleCacheManager to be the cache manager, scanned some references, there are also CompositeCacheManager and NoOpCacheManager, I thought that NoOpCacheManager was designed to make tests convenient, but what is the scene to use CompositeCacheManager and what is it different from SimpleCacheManager? 
In the next part, I'll show some codes to explain how we use SimpleCacheManager, if there is better strategy to use SimpleCacheManager?

To make the frame work, we need to add @EnableCaching at the entrance and add @Cacheable of the aim service method, cache manager implemented at the entrance.

entrance:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class Application {
            SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
        GuavaCache cache = new GuavaCache("ivan_cache",
                CacheBuilder.newBuilder().expireAfterWrite(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build());
        cacheManager.setCaches(ImmutableList.of(cache));
        return cacheManager();

}
```

Service module:

```
@Cacheable(value = { "ivan_cache" })
public void cacheTest() {
    log.info("Cache not effects.");
}
```

Comment: And the question is? How on earth would caching a `void` method work? That wouldn't add much to the cache now would it.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for answer. I displayed part of the codes, SimpleCacheManager works, my question is the following three: (1) how to understand CompositeCacheManager, what its scene and how to use?  (2) what's the differences between SimpleCacheManager and CompositeCacheManager? (3) I don't know whether the SimpleCacheManager used right, such as what type of cache can we put into cache manager except GuavaCache?